Have you it there?
In the Sherlock Holmes short story The Adventure of Wisteria Lodge (1908) Watson asks Holmes about a telegram:

Have you it there?

And I vaguely remember similar constructions in other Sherlock Holmes stories, but can’t find them right now.
This has always struck me as odd: I would expect a question to be formed using do (you have it there).
As a speaker of German, I have no trouble understanding its meaning—the word order being the same in contemporary German—but I was wondering whether this way of phrasing a question would still have been used in the early 20th century.
Or is it an anachronism?

Welcome to ELU, Philipp. You are right that it would largely be anachronistic in standard English by that date. But I suspect it was still being used in some other dialects, particularly by older speakers.

I've not read the story. For my curiosity, is the sentence structure of the telegram germane to the mystery? I can imagine Doyle using an archaic structure in such a way.

In the period they were important (including A. Conan Doyle's time) telegrams were charged by the number of words (though with a minimum), so senders generally used the shortest phrasing they expected would be understood by the (known) reader -- and even now 'telegraphic' has one meaning of 'concise, terse'

@dave_thompson_085: but "Have you it there?" is asking about the telegram; it is not the contents of the telegram.

Not exactly what you are asking, but: if you search for "have you a" irish you will find lots of results indicating that the construction have you a [noun]? is still commonplace in English as spoken in Ireland.

Related declarative and interrogative independent clauses are common:

I have it here. [Subject – Verbₚₒₛₛₑₛₛᵢₒₙ/ₑₓₚₑᵣᵢₑₙ꜀ᵢₙ₉ ₐ ₛᵢₜᵤₐₜᵢₒₙ – DO – Locative]
You have it / John / the A to Z / trouble / peace there.

             

Do I have it here?
Do you have it there?
             

But, as seen, do-support is the usual way to form the question ... or the addition of 'get' (less formal):

Have I got it here?
Have you got it there?

Though 'Have you a map?' say is quite common, especially in the UK, 'Have you got a map?' is more usual. And as Lambie says, 'Have you a map?' / 'Have you got a map?' are [very] rare in the US. But then there are plenty of British tourists.
As Paul says, 'Have you it there' is probably archaic in today's English, this was not always the case. Google 4-grams show it is still used, on rare occasions, though they do not really reflect how far it is from being the idiomatic choice:
             


have you as an interrogative BrE. AmE simply does not use it at all.

@Lambie Have you no shame?

Thank you, Edwin Ashworth. The development becomes clearer when you omit the “there”: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+you+it%2Chave+you+got+it%2Cdo+you+have+it&year_start=1800&year_end=2022&corpus=en&smoothing=3

@Araucaria-Him Well, you are British, aren't you?

Leaving out 'padding', while not affecting grammaticality, can markedly affect idiomaticity, Philipp. Compare 'Sad after his defeat, he decided to cheer himself up by playing his favourite music' with  'Sad, he decided to cheer himself up by playing his favourite music' which sounds far less natural ...  but with 'Disconsolate, he decided to cheer himself up by playing his favourite music' idiomaticity is to a degree restored.

@Lambie Pretty sure Jimmy Kimmel is American when he here asks “Have you no decency, woman?”. Have you truly forgotten the famous question put to Senator Joe McCarthy by the American — not British Senator Joe Welsh when he said "Have you no sense of decency, sir, at long last?"

@Araucaria-Him I for one certainly got your joke, as apparently did at least seven others. But not, apparently, everyone who read it. Oh well.

@tchrist Yep, dig, dig, dig and you shall find uncommon turns of phrase in AmE. Used for special purposes.  I don't think I recall ever hearing an American say: Have you a car? However, Have you got a car? is as American as apple pie. It is simply not a Britishism at all. Sorry.

- Have you a car, Mrs. Kane? - Yes, thank you. Citizen Kane

You Americans have little time for have you, do you?

Apparently yes re "have you it", "have you the", "has he it", though I'm seeing it overwhelmingly in minutes of official proceedings from the US, the UK, and South Australia. A couple of examples: such as:

From a US Congressional hearing in 1917, https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hearings/ABYk45kxvCwC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22have+you+it%22&pg=PA346&printsec=frontcover:

MR HARRISON. Will you give the committee the benefit of that knowledge?
MR LAWSON. No; I said I could not now.
MR HARRISON. Have you it in mind now?
MR LAWSON. No, I haven't it in mind now.


From "Minutes of Evidence Taken Before the Royal Commission on Militia and Volunteers" in 1904, https://www.google.com/books/edition/Minutes_of_Evidence_Taken_Before_the_Roy/sKK8ZxaLuGAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22have+you+it%22&pg=PA87&printsec=frontcover: "What is your recruiting area?" "Cambridgeshire and Isle of Ely." "Have you it all to yourself?" "Yes."

